# What it means to an order pair doesnot belong to composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Finally suppose $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ and $S$ is a relation from $B$ to $C$.  Then the *composition* of $S$ and $R$ is the relation $S\circ R$ from $A$ to $C$ defined as follows: $$S\circ R = \{(a,c)\in A\times C\mid \exists b\in B((a,b)\in R\text{ and } (b,c)\in S)\}$$

How do i write when $(a,c) \notin S \circ R$

Comment: Do you mean $(a,c)\not\in S\circ R$?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes i will fix that

Comment: You just negate the statement $\exists b\in B((a,b)\in R\text{ and }(b,c)\in S)$.

Comment: @Bye_World It will be for all  $b \in B ((a.b) \notin R$ or $(b,c) \notin S)$. But does it not mean that R and S have empty range and domain

Comment: No.  It doesn't mean that.  It means that for any $b\in B$ either $a$ is not related to $b$ in the sense of $R$ or $b$ is not related to $c$ in the sense of $S$.

Comment: @Bye_World For any b in B , a is not related to b means R has empty range

Comment: Except that it can be true that $a$ is related to $b$ -- so long as $b$ is not related to $c$ for that particular $b$.

Comment: Here's an example (someone else can probably come up with a more illuminating one, but this'll do for now): Let $R$ be $<$ on $\Bbb Z$ and $S$ be $=$ on $\Bbb Z$.  Then $R$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a<b$ and $S$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(c,d)$ such that $c=d$ (i.e. $S$ is just the set of all ordered pairs $(c,c)$).  Then $S\circ R$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,c)$ such that there exists a $b$ such that $a<b$ and $b=c$.  Hence $S\circ R$ in this case is just $R$.  So $(a,c)\not\in S\circ R$ if $a\not < c$.  So for instance $(2,1)\not\in S\circ R$.

Comment: Does you know how to simplify $\lnot(\exists x(\varphi\land\psi))$, in the sense that there will not be negation at the start of the sentence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Read my comments above, already done